# PDFBOX - header in all pages using easytable

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox and easytable https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable for creating dynamic pages which works great. But I do want header to be added in alL pages. I faced/tried below things.

> 1) Tablebuilder is created before writing rows so we can create a perfect tablebuilder since rows are dynamic.
>
> 2) Tried to insert header in middle while creating tablebuilder which again is not perfect since TableDrawer makes the rows to suffice according to row height

Any idea/help would be appreciated.

Need output similar to this project - https://github.com/eduardohl/Paginated-PDFBox-Table-Sample . only problem here being the content is not dynamic like easytable.

Comment: *"But i do want header to be added in al pages."* - do you mean table headers or page headers?

Comment: @mkl Table headers.. Example - [https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/blob/master/src/test/java/org/vandeseer/integrationtest/TwoPagesTableTest.java] . In this example need dummy header to be the first row in second page as well.

Comment: Your link returns a 404 for me.That being said, I don't know easytable good enough to help adding table headers.

Comment: I don't see how this is a PDFBox question... there's no PDFBox code in your question. There's not even easytable code. Maybe the question would be more relevant as an issue on the easytable project.

Comment: @mkl sorry for the broken link. This is indeed about pdfbox where i try to create dynamic table for which i use easytable project(that is written on pdfbox 2.0) which has plug-in setting for table,font,word break etc . All i am trying to do is create a dynamic paginated table with headers spanning in all pages using pdfbox.  Hope i made it clear now and the link works now - https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable

Comment: I've had a quick look at easytable. It appears not to support table headers yet. That support would be easy to add to the library. It is difficult, though, to add it on top, i.e. in one's own code without changing the library because easytable also (like many libraries) suffers from excessive data hiding.

Comment: @Mark *"I've implemented this by drawing a header on top of each page, along with easytable for the table's contents."* - I eventually did something similar, see my answer, using a separate easytable table for the headers. *"I'm not sure why you think it "suffers from excessive data hiding""* - I still think so. I would have liked to extend the `TableDrawer` class to customize the table drawing process. It is the natural class to extend. But most member variables and methods therein are private, so extending is futile.

Comment: @mkl I didn't understand what you meant by data hiding. Yes it would be really nice if we could just extend TableDrawer to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer had been written at an earlier time when easytable had not yet supported repeating table headers. Meanwhile it does, see [the answer by philonous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100581/1729265), the easytable author.*

easytable does not support repeating table headers or footers. *Not yet* I should say because this feature actually is easy to implement.

It is difficult, though, to implement *on top of* easytable because that library (like many others) suffers from excessive data hiding: many interesting member variables and methods are `private`, so extending the classes is not a viable option.

But what you can do is handle the header rows as a separate table which you draw again and again! The downside is a bit of duplicity of settings.

In case of the test code `TwoPagesTableTest` you referred to, it can be changed like this:

```
final Table.TableBuilder tableHeaderBuilder = Table.builder()
        .addColumnOfWidth(200)
        .addColumnOfWidth(200);

CellText dummyHeaderCell = CellText.builder()
        .text("Header dummy")
        .backgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        .textColor(Color.WHITE)
        .borderWidth(1F)
        .build();

tableHeaderBuilder.addRow(
        Row.builder()
                .add(dummyHeaderCell)
                .add(dummyHeaderCell)
                .build());

Table tableHeader = tableHeaderBuilder.build();

final Table.TableBuilder tableBuilder = Table.builder()
        .addColumnOfWidth(200)
        .addColumnOfWidth(200);

CellText dummyCell = CellText.builder()
        .text("dummy")
        .borderWidth(1F)
        .build();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    tableBuilder.addRow(
            Row.builder()
                    .add(dummyCell)
                    .add(dummyCell)
                    .build());
}

TableDrawer drawer = TableDrawer.builder()
        .table(tableBuilder.build())
        .startX(50)
        .endY(50F) // note: if not set, table is drawn over the end of the page
        .build();

final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

float startY = 100F;

do {
    TableDrawer headerDrawer = TableDrawer.builder()
            .table(tableHeader)
            .startX(50)
            .build();

    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    document.addPage(page);
    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
        headerDrawer.startY(startY);
        headerDrawer.contentStream(contentStream).draw();
        drawer.startY(startY - tableHeader.getHeight());
        drawer.contentStream(contentStream).draw();
    }

    startY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 50;
} while (!drawer.isFinished());

document.save("twoPageTable-repeatingHeader.pdf");
document.close();
```

*([RepeatingTableHeaders](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/easytable/RepeatingTableHeaders.java#L109) test `createTwoPageTableRepeatingHeader`)*

As you see, the code first creates a separate `Table tableHeader` containing only the header row. This table then is added first on each page and a part of the body rows table is added thereafter.

The result: table headers on each page...

[image: screen shot]

A word of warning: This is a proof of concept, I have only tested with the table generation code from `TwoPagesTableTest`. For production code you should apply further tests.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm the author of easytable.) I added this as a feature request: https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/issues/27. Pull requests (to the develop branch) are also always very welcome! ;) The library started as an extraction of some two classes in a completely different project – I wanted to save others from going through excessive effort just for drawing a simple table and therefore put it on github. It suffers from more issues than "excessive data hiding" (which I actually wasn't aware of but is true!) so just open an issue for anything that can be improved! :)

Comment: @philonous As mentioned above, easytable is by far not the only library with excessive data hiding. So first of all it's great you did publish your table creation code at all, everything else is merely a matter of improving it! ;)

Comment: @mkl Brilliant. As you have mentioned i was not able to make it in easier way since most of the variables are private . Never struck me to add to 2 drawer :) . Also achieved this via boxable api .

Comment: @mkl do you please know other lib or example on top of pdfbox to create complexe table ? thank you

Comment: @bee I only have done some simple experiments with easytable and boxable but I have not checked them for their features concerning complex table builds. Depending on what exactly your *complex table* makes complex, one probably can circumvent the complexity, e.g. like here doing table headers by means of a separate table.

Comment: @mkl thank you i mainly want right way to manage multi page it seems out of scope to me and can't find good algo to achieve this like, try to add 1 or two or _n_ row if it will fit in current page if not add to next page like this I can keep 1,2 or _n_ pages in same pages, thank if you have some example

Comment: My only easytable using code is this answer. But here you see the `startY` and `endY` values explicitly. You merely have to compare them and decide if the span between them is big enough for you.

Comment: @mkl thank you. as I comment on related easytable's github issue im not sure this code snippet is enough to achieve these two feature [repeat subheader if not finish in previous page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1psBUukZq1_scaT4_gposYnWKq9k29-8T/view) because I don't know how many element are drawed from my list. Another one is if I want [group some rows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFLgZlqwnYOr-3lAv52PV6KxG3xTQaA_/view)  so keep them together like here "Ana"

Comment: Ah. Well, I think easytable could be extended to allow something like that. Probably one should even change one's perspective: The current easytable implementation allows essentially to draw a number of rows limited by coordinates. Probably one can use that API as lowlevel API underneath a higher level table creation API that organizes headers of different kinds, groups, spans, etc. But content creation is not really my field of expertise...

Comment: @bee Give a try for boxable api which uses pdfbox and it is only for complex table creation and as far as i know only thing missing in it is href implementation inside cell.

Comment: This answer is out of date because repeating headers in easytable are now supported.

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to @mkl's answer and its comments: In current versions of the library there is a class of its own for this very requirement.

So your code basically boils down to something like:

```
try (final PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {

    RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder()
            .table(createTable())
            .startX(50)
            .startY(100F)
            .endY(50F) // note: if not set, table is drawn over the end of the page
            .build()
            .draw(() -> document, () -> new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4), 50f);

    document.save("your-awesome-document.pdf");
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because easytable now supports repeating headers.