# Add rows dynamically to table - Easytable (PDFBox)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I've the following method in order to create my table header in easytable ([easytable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable))

```
    public void addHeader(){
    myTable = Table.builder()
            .addColumnsOfWidth(widthColumn,widthColumn,widthColumn)
            .addRow(
                    Row.builder()
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Id").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Name").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Town").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                            .build())

            .build();
}
```

Then, the table is drawn:

```
    public void drawTable() {
    tableDrawer = TableDrawer.builder()
            .contentStream(contentStream)
            .startX(marginX)
            .startY(page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - marginY)
            .table(myTable)
            .build();

    tableDrawer.draw();
}
```

The table header is drawn properly but.. How would be the method for add rows dynamically? Do I have to draw a new table? Can I add rows to the already created table?

Thanks..

Comment: You can call `addRow` multiple times.

Comment: Yes mkl, but I need a dynamic method.. Not always i'll need the same number of rows..

Comment: Do you probably mean like in the `for` loop in the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242192/1729265)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, done.. Thank you @mkl :)

```
    public void addMyTable(ArrayList<Person> alp) {
    Table.TableBuilder tb = Table.builder().addColumnsOfWidth(widthColumn,widthColumn,widthColumn);
    tb.addRow(
            Row.builder()
                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Id").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Name").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                    .add(TextCell.builder().text("Town").borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                    .build())

            .build();

    for(Person p : alp){
        tb.addRow(
                Row.builder()
                        .add(TextCell.builder().text(p.getId()).borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.WHITE).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                        .add(TextCell.builder().text(p.getName()).borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.WHITE).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                        .add(TextCell.builder().text(p.getTown()).borderWidth(1).backgroundColor(Color.WHITE).horizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).build())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
    myTable = tb.build();
}
```